# Python: Default value in for loop

Tags: python, django

The for loop has 3 iterations (and will be more soon). Is it possible to define a standard value for assign_organizer after the second loop?

```
    [...]
    name = ['Super Bowl 2018', 'Jon Summer 2019', 'Jon Summer 2020', ]
    slug = ['super-bowl-2018', 'jon-summer-2019', 'jon-summer-2020', ]
    first_organizer = Organizer.objects.all().first()
    last_organizer = Organizer.objects.all().last()
    assign_organizer = [first_organizer, last_organizer, ]

    for i in range(len(name)):
        Event.objects.create(
            organizer=assign_organizer[i],
            name=name[i],
            slug=slug[i],
            status='on_sale',
            short_description=lorem,
            additional_information=lorem_long,
            venue_name=lorem,
            venue_address=lorem,
            start_date='2018-05-26 18:12:58.556925+02',
            end_date='2018-05-26 18:12:58.556925+02',
            facebook_event_link=lorem,
            banner=lorem,
        )
```

**__Update__:**

I now tried the solution suggested in the comments, however, I am not getting the expected outcome. (I now instead of having a default, just decided it's better to start at the beginning again.)

**Expected:**

TEST 1:  A
TEST 2:  1
Assigned:  a1

TEST 1:  B
TEST 2:  2
Assigned:  a2

TEST 1:  C
TEST 2:  3
Assigned:  a1

**Actual outcome:**
However, it is instead stopping after the second loop.

```
test1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
test2 = ['1', '2', '3']

assigned_raw = ['a1', 'a2']
assigned = itertools.chain(assigned_raw)

for a, b, c in zip(test1, test2, assigned):

    print("TEST 1: ", a)
    print("TEST 2: ", b)
    print("Assigned: ", c)
```

Comment: What you mean by `standard value for assign_organizer after the second loop?`

Comment: You can wrap it in a `itertools.chain(assign_organizer, itertools.repeat(default_organizer))`.

Comment: And you probably better use `zip` here.

Comment: I mean it should always be first_organizer after the second loop, no matter if 3, 5 or 9 iterations.

Comment: `for i in range(len(iterable)):` is always bad. use `zip()` or `enumerate()` instead.

Comment: Okay thank you for that tip, I will try to understand how to solve that with zip().

Comment: I managed to implement the zip(), however i am struggling with the itertools now, anyone knows what I am doing wrong? (see update above)